# Riemann-Siegel formula for Dirichlet characters

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, zeta-functions

After unearthing and giving a proof of what is now known as the Riemann--Siegel formula for the Riemann zeta function enabling the computation of $\zeta(1/2+iT)$ in time $O(T^{1/2})$,
in [1943](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968761?seq=1) Siegel published a generalization for L-functions of Dirichlet characters. If $m$ denotes the conductor of the character, it
seems to me that the time is now $O((mT)^{1/2})+O(m)$. The $(mT)^{1/2}$ term is clearly
necessary, but I do not see how to remove the $O(m)$ term, which is quite annoying in practice
when $m$ becomes large.

One of the reasons I ask is that in a relatively recent arXiv paper (arXiv:[1703.01414v7](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01414))
K.~Fisher describes another algorithm which runs in $O((mT)^{1/2})$, without the $O(m)$.
Implementations of both algorithms seem to show that Siegel's is considerably faster
(i.e., the implicit big-Oh constant is much smaller), but only when $m$ is small, and even
for $m$ as small as $10^5$ the $O(m)$ term becomes a huge problem and Fisher's algorithm is
much faster. Does anyone have any idea
about this (sorry if too technical/specialized) ?

Comment: Dear professor Cohen. I took the liberty to add the links to the cited papers. Is Siegel's article the correct one?

Comment: What about the Gauss sum ?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct link, thanks.